# Add inputs values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I created the next code:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("btn");
b.addEventListener('click', function () {
 var a  = document.createElement("input");
 document.getElementById('container').appendChild(a);
});
var c  = document.getElementById('btn2');
c.addEventListener('click',function () {
  document.querySelector("input").remove();
});
var d  = document.getElementById('btn3');
d.addEventListener('click', function () {
 var arr = [];
 var items = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr.push(items.value))
 }
});
```

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
#container input{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
#container input:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#container{
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;

}
button{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>To do list</h1>
<div id="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
</div>
<button style="margin: auto" id="btn">push</button>
<button style="margin: auto" id="btn2">delete</button>
<button style="margin: auto" id="btn3">add</button>
```

This code should add all values from each input in array and output then on the screen. I get only the number of inputs, but how to get the values from each input?

Comment: `console.log(arr.push(...))` will return the new length of the array- is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement more optimal syntax, using spread (`...`) operator, `.map` function and arrow (`=>`) function to make the code more effective and readable:

```
var arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(elem => elem.value);
```

```js
var b = document.getElementById("btn");
b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var a  = document.createElement("input");
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(a);
});

var c  = document.getElementById('btn2');
c.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector("input").remove();
});

var d  = document.getElementById('btn3');
d.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(elem => elem.value);
    console.log(arr);
});
```

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
#container input{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
#container input:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#container{
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;

}
button{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>To do list</h1>
<div id="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
</div>
<button style="margin: auto" id="btn">push</button>
<button style="margin: auto" id="btn2">delete</button>
<button style="margin: auto" id="btn3">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`push()` method returns length of array and you are printing it. You need to log array after pushing elements to it.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
  arr.push(items.value)
 }
console.log(arr)
```